# backup compression ratio in SQL 2012 worse than in SQL 2008

Tags: backup, sql, compression

We have SQL 2008 Enterprise with TDE enabled and upgraded to SQL 2012 with TDE still enabled.  Everything works fine except that I am getting worse backup compression than in SQL 2008.  I do understand the limitation with Compression when TDE is turned on.  However, this limitation is worse when I upgraded to SQL 2012 with TDE enabled.   I was expecting to obtain the same compression ratio or better in SQL 2012 than SQL 2008 with TDE enabled.  I have done quite a bit of research but no luck to understand this puzzle.  Can anyone point me to some KB or documentation why SQL 2012 backup compression ratio with TDE enable is worse than with SQL 2008?

Comment: `I was expecting to obtain the same compression ratio or better in SQL 2012 than SQL 2008 with TDE enabled.` - Why? Because it's newer? What data or information do you have that suggests it should be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Is your database recovery model Full? Simple? Bulk-logged?
I remember upgrading SQL Server 2008 to 2012, and my database that was simple was now set to Full.  When I ran the backup, the backup was larger as well since the the Full recovery model also backs up the larger translation logs.